# Android - Cannot get custom LinearLayout view to move with TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I'm trying to do something simple - I have a custom LinearLayout view that I want to move across the screen using the TranslateAnimation. To test out the base case, I put the code in the constructor of my custom view to translate it as soon as it is created. But nothing happens, and the view stays put. Any idea why? I have pasted the relevant code below:

My custom LinearLayout View:

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_picture);


        //Test simple translate animation
        TranslateAnimation translateMyView = new TranslateAnimation(10, 10, 5, 5);
        translateMyView.setFillAfter(true);
        translateMyView.setDuration(1000);
        this.startAnimation(translateMyView);

    }
```

The XML of this custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example Text"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/my_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the way I have added this view in the main activity's view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
    android:id="@+id/main_view">


    <com.pratikthaker.MyView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Couple questions... Why are you calling the animation in the constructor? I would think that the animation will be executed before the view is ever drawn or even added the to view hierarchy. Secondly if your custom view is just a TextView with an ImageView below it why not use a Compound Drawable with a TextView?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie - Good questions. (1) I'm calling the animator in the constructor as a test.  I actually want it to fire on a fling gesture - I'll give that a try (2) The textView and imageView are just a starting point - the custom view will eventually have other elements like buttons, etc.

Comment: Also note: you're only moving it 5 pixels vertically/horizontally. Are you sure you can even see that kind of minor movement on your device? Not to mention: if you're doing it in the constructor, it's very likely the Animation is occurring before you're even able to see it happen.

Comment: @Guardanis - That's it! (1) I was moving it too little (2) I was calling it in the constructor so it was already executed (3) had initial and final displacement values as the same. Changing all this got it working! Thank you!